# How to get a lower bound on a chromatic index from a chromatic polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, coloring

I'm working on an exercise,

> A graph $H$ has chromatic polynomial $$P_H(k)=k(k-1)(k-2)^3(k-3)^2(k^2-4k+6).$$ What is the chromatic number of $H$? Prove that the chromatic index of $H$ is at least $5$.

Could someone gives me a pointer for the second part?

---

#### Efforts so far

I see that $$P_H(1)=P_H(2)=P_H(3)=0\neq4\times3\times2^3\times1^2\times6=P_H(4)$$ so the chromatic number is $\chi(H)=4$.

I know the chromatic index $\chi'(H)$ satisfies $\Delta(H)\leq\chi'$, where $\Delta(H)$ is the maximum vertex-degree in $H$, but I can't see how to show $5\leq\Delta(H)$.

I also know $$P_H(k)=k^n-mk^{n-1}+\text{lower order terms},$$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in $H$ and $m$ is the number of edges in $H$, and I see that
\begin{align}
P_H(k)
& = k(k-1)(k-2)^3(k-3)^2(k^2-4k+6) \\
& = k(k-1)(k^3-6k^2+12k+4)(k^2-6k+9)(k^2-4k+6) \\
& = k^9 + (-1-6-6-4)k^8 + \text{lower order terms} \\
& = k^9-17k^8 + \text{lower order terms}
\end{align} so $n=9,m=17$.

I could handshake edges with vertices to get $$\sum_{v\in V(H)}d(v)=2m=34,$$ but I don't see that this immediately implies $5\leq\Delta(H)$, since $$34<36=9\times4.$$

I had a go at rewriting $P_H(k)$ as a sum of expressions $(k-a_i)^{b_i}$ but quickly got the impression that that's difficult so I gave up.

And now I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a proper edge coloring, each color can cover at most $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ edges, so you need at least $\lceil m/\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \rceil$ colors to cover all $m$ edges.  Substituting $n=9$ and $m=17$ yields
$$\chi' \ge \left\lceil \frac{17}{\lfloor 9/2 \rfloor} \right\rceil = \left\lceil \frac{17}{4} \right\rceil = 5.$$